# I do not know how to vectorize my function

Tags: python, pandas

Here is my function:

```
def if_rule2(row):
    item1 = row['first_item']
    item2 = row['second_item']
    weight = row['weight']
    if item2 == item1:
        basic_score = weight
        add_score = 0
    elif item1 in ('No') and item2 in ('Yes'):
        basic_score = weight
        add_score = weight * 0.1
    elif item1 in ('No') and item2 in ('Yes'):
        baisc_score = 1
        add_score = 0
    else:
        basic_score = 0
        add_score = 0
    return [basic_score, add_score]
```

I need to speed up my code a little and I am interested by the improvement of vectorization. I need to vectorize my function so it would accept:

```
df[['basic_score', 'additional_score']] = if_rule(df['first_item'], df['second_item'], df['weight'])
```

instead of:

```
df[['basic_score', 'additional_score']] = df.apply(if_rule2, axis=1)
```

How can I do this..?

Comment: Explain your code properly and edit your title.

Comment: I think there's a typo: the second and the third conditions are the same

Comment: Use nested [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) calls...

Answer (score 0):

This solution does not include the third condition because it's the same as the second, but you can get the idea.

- First define the columns with the `else` condition
- Define a boolean vector with the specific condition
- Rewrite the columns for the specific slices defined by the vector

```
# default
df['basic_score'] = 0
df['add_score'] = 0

# first condition
first_condition = (df['first_item'] == df['second_item'])
df.loc[first_condition, 'basic_score'] = df.loc[first_condition, 'weight']
df.loc[first_condition, 'add_score'] = 0

# second condition
second_condition = ((df['first_item'] == 'No') & (df['second_item'] == 'Yes'))
df.loc[second_condition, 'basic_score'] = df.loc[second_condition, 'weight']
df.loc[second_condition, 'add_score'] = df.loc[second_condition, 'weight'] * 0.1
```